# How to find an element by multiple attributes and add to that specific one?

Tags: jquery

How do I get this element:

```
<input type="search" class="" placeholder="" aria-controls="surchargeTable">
```

and add an attribute to it:

```
<input type="search" class="" placeholder="" aria-controls="surchargeTable" ng-model="model.searchValue">
```

I tried this:

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
    var temp = $('input[aria-controls=surchargeTable]');
    temp.attr("ng-model", "model.searchValue");
});
```

That doesn't give me the right element (unless I am misunderstanding what it should do).

result:

```
<input type="search" class="" placeholder="" aria-controls="surchargeTable">
```

nothing changed

There is only one element on the page with an aria-controls="surchargeTable" but there are multiple search type inputs.

Is it possible to just grab the one input on the page with the correct aria-controls value?

Comment: Your example adds `model.searchValue` whereas your code adds `searchValue`. Could this be related?

Comment: Give it an ID and select it by that? `$('#someId').attr('ng-model', 'searchValue');`

Comment: Your code works just fine (aside from the different name your example uses as pointed out by @Curt) http://jsfiddle.net/84y81a2v/ Please show the rest of your code/page in case it is another issue :)

Comment: @Jezzabeanz The code is generated by datatables and I don't want to change the source

Comment: @curt Yes that is one issue, but it doesn't add anything to the element not even the wrong one

Comment: How are you viewing the DOM to see the change?

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie Chrome dev tools

Comment: Is it possible the `aria-controls=` is added after your code, i.e. dynamically? Is it in the plain page source when you `View Source` in the browser?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/84482/discussion-between-robert-and-trueblueaussie).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From comments/discussion, your elements *do not exist in the page* when your code is run.

You need to delay execution until they do exist.

Change the order of execution so that your code runs last, or delay your code using `setTimeout`.

e.g.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    setTimeout(function () {
        var temp = $('input[aria-controls=surchargeTable]');
        temp.attr("ng-model", "model.searchValue");
    }, 1);
});
```

You really need to identify what is adding the inputs first.

Comment: What is the purpose of the 1 millisecond timeout?

Comment: @Curt If you can't control the order of startup execution that will delay the code by one browser render cycle. Making sure all startup plugins completed before it runs.